# Lottery, cumulative distribution function, variance

Tags: statistics

Suppose a lottery is played like this: You must pay $\$5$ to play. Then, you select three numbers from $\{0, 1, 2, ..., 9\}$, with each of the three numbers being diﬀerent (order does not matter). Let’s suppose that you choose the numbers $4, 7$, and $9$. The lottery organizers choose the winning numbers in the same manner (three non-repeating numbers), with each combination of three numbers being equally likely.

Payouts are as follows: If your numbers match exactly one of the winning numbers, you get your $5$ dollars back. If you match exactly two of the winning numbers, you get your $5$ dollars back, plus an extra $5$ dollars. If you match all three numbers, you get the $5$ dollars plus an extra $50$ dollars. Let the  random variable $X$ represent your net winnings from this game (proﬁt minus cost), in dollars.

**(a)** Give the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

**(b)** Calculate $\mathrm{Var}(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, the winning numbers are $\{0,1,2\}$.

- One can pick the $3$ numbers in $\binom{10}{3}=120$ ways.
- One can pick only non-winning numbers in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways ($X=-5$).
- One can pick 1 winning number and 2 non-winning numbers in $\binom{7}{2}\times\binom{3}{1}$ ways ($X=0$).
- One can pick 2 winning numbers and 1 non-winning number in $\binom{7}{1}\times\binom{3}{2}$ ways ($X=5$).
- One can pick all 3 winning numbers in $1=\binom{3}{3}$ ways ($X=50$).

Thus

1. $P(X=-5)=\frac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{35}{120}$
2. $P(X=0)=\frac{3\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{63}{120}$
3. $P(X=5)=\frac{3\times 7}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{21}{120}$
4. $P(X=50)=\frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{1}{120}$

Can you finish the computation?